# How can I shake an Android Emulator device in Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I need to test a newly developed app on multiple Android device emulators through Android Studio.

This app has multiple environments wherein this is hosted, like, qa, UAT, Production. I can change the environment through a screen that comes only after shaking a real device.

Unfortunately, Android Studio 3 does not give a direct option to shake the device. How can I achieve this shake action in the emulator ?

Answer (score 12):

Try

`Ctrl + m` for windows

`⌘ + m` for Mac OS-X

Ok Try this ...
Goto `Setting->Virtual Sensors` in emulator menu

Click on `Move` checkbox

Now try moving `X Y Z` seekbar

You can use this code snap to detect shake
[ShakeDetectionDemo](https://github.com/spaceotech/ShakeDetectionDemo)

[image: Emulator]

[image: move emulator]

Comment: This also doesn't work. Plus the app I am working with detects shake by itself, as it will open a menu on shake, so would not need a shake detection separately.

Comment: The threshold I use to detect shake works fine on my phone but not in the emulator.  Lowering the threshold for the emulator seems to be the only true solution I've encountered.

Answer (score 7):

To simulate a 1 second shake from command line (CLI) you can do the following:

```
adb emu sensor set acceleration 100:100:100; sleep 1; adb emu sensor set acceleration 0:0:0
```

Comment: This command works for me. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me (Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1).

Answer (score 1):

Shake with one command line:

```
{ echo "auth $(cat ~/.emulator_console_auth_token)"; echo "sensor set acceleration 0:0:0"; sleep 1; echo "sensor set acceleration 100:100:100"; sleep 1; } | telnet localhost 5554
```

- 5554 - port of the emulator (on top of window).
- ~/.emulator_console_auth_token - auth-token of the emulator (to access sensor command).

Demonstration video: https://youtu.be/_vYvx6iqZ1I